# Using Capistrano to deploy a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am new to Capistrano and this is my first attempt using it to deploy my rails application. I believe I have my config/deploy.rb setup properly, but before I do

```
cap production deploy:setup
```

I want to make sure that no harm will happen to my database. The database for this project is already set and has data in it. I could not figure out if doing

```
cap production deploy:setup
```

will destroy my production database and re-create it as an empty DB. Opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cap deploy:setup`](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html)

> When you run this command, Capistrano will SSH to your server, enter
>   the directory that you specified in the deploy_to variable, and create
>   a special directory structure that’s required for Capistrano to work
>   properly. If something is wrong with the permissions or SSH access,
>   you will get error messages. Look closely at the output Capistrano
>   gives you while the command is running.

**This command will do nothing with your database.**

Comment: So, it will not try to initialize the DB?

Comment: only create directory on remote server. **Nothing more**. Capistrano doesn't have any "inbox" task for work with database. Only one "migrate" task if you run `cap deploy:cold`. `cap deploy` can run migrations if have pending.